# How to connect Kerberized Hive via ODBC and avoid the "No credentials cache found" error

Tags: hive, odbc, kerberos

I am trying to connect to a HiveServer2 (Hive 0.14 from HDP 2.2) on a kerberized cluster from a windows machine using ODBC.

I have followed the guide at http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Product-Guide-HDP-2.1-v1.01.pdf

When I try to test my ODBC connection (using the "Test" button in the ODBC Driver setup form) I always get the error message

[image: Hive ODBC Kerberos Connection Test Error]

Besides that, there is also the strange fact that when testing the connection I always get prompted for a new Kerberos ticket, although I can clearly see a ticket already in the ticket manager.

Best Regards

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

And now found out that when actually using the connection from Excel, the MIT Kerberos Ticket Manager needs to be running normally.
  So there is a contradiction, both won't work at the same time.

When you set up the connection follow the advice above, so you can test it easily. But when using from Excel do a reboot first (or maybe kill the process and restart the service, I tested only with reboot) and don't mind that it stops working from Test button in the ODBC driver setup (shouldn't be any need to access that anymore anyway)

br,
    o-p

Comment: Yea, it just boils down to that the application that tries to access the ticket manager and the ticket manager itself should run as the same user. In the case of the DSN administrative tool, that is always started as the administrator user while Excel or most other programs are just run as your currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

Run the MIT Ticket Manager as administrator (i.e kill any already running version of it and then right click on the MIT Kerberos Ticket Manager Icon -> "Run as administrator".

Thanks to my colleague Olli-Pekka Saxell for finding this.